# Peticion http con AngularJS a un Servidor PHP que responde con status -1

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, json

Estoy enviando una petición http desde AngularJS (Angular 1) a un servidor PHP y me responde esto:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": -1,
  "config": {
    "method": "POST",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "data": {},
    "url": "http://api.elpozon.com/rest/login",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    }
  },
  "statusText": ""
}
```

Cuando lo hago desde POSTMAN, me devuelve la información de logueo.

Esta es la función en AngularJS (Angular 1) que ejecuta la petición.

```
$scope.intentoDeLoginPozon = function(){

        var datapost = {
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    user : $scope.username,
                    pass: $scope.password
                },
                url: 'http://api.elpozon.com/rest/login',
                headers:{
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            };

            $http(datapost).then(function successCallback(response){
                $scope.mensaje = response;


            }, function errorCallback(response){
                $scope.error = response;

            }); 
    }
```

No tengo nada de informacion de como esta programado el Servidor en PHP.

Que explicacion existe para esto?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que es la misma petición? ¿Mismos parámetros?

Comment: Si, son los mismos parametros. 
Hablé con el administrador del servidor php y me dice que olvido colocarle los headers, especialmente este: 
'Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"

ahora cuando le hago la peticion, el server me devuelve la info del usuario.

Comment: Agrega eso como respuesta y marca como respondida en 24 horas :D así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio (%de preguntas resueltas) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, son los mismos parametros. Hablé con el administrador del servidor php y me dice que olvido colocarle los headers, especialmente este: 
`'Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"` 
ahora cuando le hago la peticion, el server me devuelve la info del usuario.